# PHP Date Conversion keeps giving wrong time?

Tags: php, date

I'm using the following code to try and convert time.

```
date("Y-m-d H:m:s", strtotime("20170905T110000-0400"));
```

However, it keeps returning "2017-09-05 11:09:00" not "2017-09-05 11:00:00"

Why is this? Is there any simplistic way to fix this?

**It won't allow me to delete this as it has an answer. Very silly of me. Long weekend**

Comment: look into dateTime too it has more functionality

Answer (score 5):

You should use 'i' for the minutes, 'm' stands for 'month'

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("20170905T110000-0400"));
```

Comment: Wow, that was so silly of me. Sorry to waste everyone's time.

Comment: No worries. I recognized it immediately because i have done it too.